# Rails Flash doesn't behave as what the Rails Guide says

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-flash

According to the official [flash section on Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#the-flash):

> **The Flash**
>
> The flash is a special part of the session which is cleared with each request. This means that values stored there will only be available in the next request, which is useful for passing error messages etc.
>
> ...
>
> **flash.now**
>
> By default, adding values to the flash will make them available to the next request, but sometimes you may want to access those values in the same request.

However, after doing some test, I found that `flash` is available in the current & next request. And `flash.now` is **only** available in the current request.

Is the Rails Guide incorrect? Or maybe I miss something?

```
# Controller action
def test_flash
  flash[:notice] = "This is a flash msg."
end

# test_flash.html.erb
<% flash.each do |name, msg| -%>
  <%= content_tag :div, msg, class: name %>
<% end -%>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I won't say the document is incorrect, but I agree it could be more clear.
It should be phrased something like:

> Flash is clear after next request, therefore it's available in the current
>   request and next request. If you only want it be available in the current
>   request, not along with the next request, use `flash.now`.

On the other hand, don't you think something is not available in the current
request, given current flash API, as a hash like object, it would be quite
weird? For example:

```
flash[:notice] = 'nnf'
puts flash[:notice] # => nil
```

It would make more sense with `write` and `read` if that's the case.

Answer (score 1):

You have read it incorrectly. `flash.now` is only available to the current request. `flash` (without now) is the only one that will be available to the next request.

The sentence you read above - is actually talking about plain `flash` (to begin with), and only then introduces `flash.now` as a contrast at the end of the paragraph.